# How to get overall RAM usage (e.g. 57%) on Linux

Tags: linux

I am wondering how you can get the system RAM usage and present it in percent using bash, for example.

Sample output:

```
57%
```

Comment: do you mean something like `$ free -g` ? or specifically a percentage number only?

Comment: You calculate it with something like `awk '/MemTotal:/{total=$2}/MemFree:/{free=$2}END{print free*100/total}' /proc/meminfo`

Comment: [Welcome to StackOverflow](http://StackOverflow.com/tour) - Please read our [ask] page.
Good questions tend to receive quicker, better answers from the community.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a bash script, I just came up with this.

There may be more efficient ways of doing it but I believe this is what you are looking for:

```
#!/bin/bash

# grab the second line of the ouput produced by the command: free -g (displays output in Gb)
secondLine=$(free -g | sed -n '2p')

#split the string in secondLine into an array
read -ra ADDR <<< "$secondLine"

#get the total RAM from array
totalRam="${ADDR[1]}"

#get the used RAM from array
usedRam="${ADDR[2]}"

# calculate and display the percentage
pct="$(($usedRam*100/$totalRam))"
echo "$pct%"
```

if you save this into a file (call it `pct.sh`), then you can run it by

```
$./pct.sh
33%
```

**Note**
`bash` does not support floats, only integers (IIRC) so the precision of the calculation is rounded.

If you need more precision, you might need to use a different shell that supports floats, like `zsh`

**Credit where credit is due**: created with help from:
[1](https://www.binarytides.com/linux-command-check-memory-usage/)
[2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421083/bash-how-to-calculate-percentage-from-number)
[3](https://www.tutorialkart.com/bash-shell-scripting/bash-split-string/)

Comment: Does this give current Ram usage? or total from when PC was booted to present time?

Comment: i thought i did back then, was just scrolling down and read i cant upvote unless i have +15 rep, sorry.

Comment: `free -k` in the above script gives a closer answer for me.